# Do Eclipse IDE have support to java code completion into EL expression?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, autocomplete, el

I am recently testing Eclipse IDE for my jsf web project using primefaces. But I find that it doesn't fill me in with java code embedded within the value of an EL expression like other Ides like Netbeans do. Could it be configured so that Eclipse can recognize it?

for example

```
filterBy="#{vers.version}" filterMatchMode="contains">
```

In Netbeans when I write these

```
#{vers.version}
```

Within the String value of the tag it recognizes me that it is java code and autocompletes me using Ctrl + space but Eclipse does not

Answer (score 0):

The JBossTools(https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools) plugin, provides JSF support, includind autocompleting, to Eclipse. Give a try.

Personally, to JSF, I prefer to use NetBeans.